# Resources for learning to use AJAX with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'v been reading about AJAX and using it for getting faster webpage content and lots of useful functions, but most documentation is with PHP, currently on my job we are working on a ASP.NET with C# on server side webpage, where page documents are .aspx, it is not MVC application. I haven't found enough material to learn to use AJAX with ASP, please link me some, or give a simple example for something like checking if an username already exists on a database, which is one of the functions I want to implement on a user registration form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will get enough material for ASP.NET AJAX on internet. So this is the link which will give you desired output.

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2297/how-to-check-whether-username-exists-in-database-without-refreshing-pa

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on whether you are trying to get this work done quickly, or get to understand this well while you build this. I try to use the latter approach. If your foundations are good enough for any topic, you wont have much trouble later on.

So, if you are starting to work on ASP.NET Web Forms and AJAX, it would be beneficial to

0) stay away from the ASP.NET AJAX Controls Toolkit and UI controls such as UpdatePanel. I feel they make AJAX-enabled ASP.NET web pages look simpler to create, but dont do much to get you into the AJAX mindset.

1) start with using XmlHttpRequest in your client-side JavaScript code and WebMethods or HTTP handlers in your server-side code

2) then, use JS libs like jQuery instead of simple Javascript calls

3) start using ASP.NET Web API on the server side

Answer (score 0):

Try this.I hit two birds(Ajax and WebAPI) when i read this a month ago.It only discussed the basics but i think it would be enough to get through on your own after reading this.

[Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/832045/Implementing-a-Basic-REST-Based-ASP-NET-Web-API-Se)

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/832045/Implementing-a-Basic-REST-Based-ASP-NET-Web-API-Se